# How to run unit tests against an app using an embedded framework without x86_x64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, linker

We need to integrate into our iOS app a framework that doesn't target x86_x64. We don't have access to that framework source code and we've been informed that they would release it for that architecture in a couple of months. Meanwhile our unit test target doesn't compile with the following linker error:

```
ld: framework not found FrameworkName for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

I've tried adding an linker flag for `Any iOS Simulator SDK` with the value `-weak_framework FrameworkName`. By doing so we can run the app on simulator but the test target crash with the same linker error.

Any idea how to setup the build settings/phase so that we can run our unit test suite? Thanks!

Also note that we need to add that framework as an embedded binaries.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry @BEm we simply isolated the framework on a branch and merged a protocol to represent the framework in master. Then we waited to receive the new version of the framework that targetted the correct architecture.